# Can I save tribesmen from drowning?

Tags: from-dust

When playing From Dust, sometimes tribesmen get dragged out to sea and then flail around for a time before drowning. Is there anything I can do to rescue them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's not too deep, you could use evaporate and/or jellify water then remove it from around them and Moses yourself a path up to land.

I usually just ignore them for their incompetence.

Comment: And I usually even add more water on them to punish them :) Who said you always have to be a good god?!

Answer (score 0):

You can also throw water next to them so the waves that result in the surplus water will move them in the other direction. This is more difficult than Nick T.'s solution but I managed to save some totem-holders this way