# How to deal with natural disasters?

Tags: from-dust

I just started playing From Dust, and I find it rather clunky to control.  While building a bridge as part of the objective, my villagers will randomly start drowning, my village will randomly get hit by a tsunami, lava will pour down the mountaintop, or any number of unfortunate things may happen.  I want to help my villagers, but only seem to hurt them.

What am I doing wrong, or what can I do more effectively to help my villagers?

Comment: Note: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26957/can-i-save-tribesmen-from-drowning) is a related question, but more specific than what I'm asking.

Comment: blasphemy!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volcanos and tsunamis are the natural forces of the game that you must learn to deal with.  For either, you can create walls with lava (or lesser ones with dirt) to either redirect the flow of the undesired element, as in the second tsunami level.

Comment: I probably should have been clearer - I understand the general principles of the game, but find that my actions always have unforeseen consequences.  For example, If I pick up some dirt at one part of a stream, it can lead to more water than before running downstream.  As a result, it covers a previously built bridge.  I was hoping for general tips on avoiding such problems

Comment: @Dave, it sounds like you've identified the problems to your general issues, do you have something more specific that is confounding you?

Comment: I guess not - I'm just not used to finding a game that seems like it should be so simple so difficult :)

Answer (score 3):

You should get the knowledge stones or whatever they are called. They will protect your buildings against fire or water. Other than that, all I can say is to use your breaths actively while monitoring the people you send out on missions.